# VBA : How to define a large set of string variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying (in VBA) to define a large number of string variables. The brute force would be :

`Dim Port1 as String 
Dim Port2 as String 
etc…`

Unpleasant for say 100 variables. There must be a more intelligent solution.
I have tried :

`Dim n As Integer
For n = 1 To 100
  Dim "Port" & n as String
Next n`

and variations of it without success.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or share an example.

Comment: Look into arrays, it will allow you to load it up with a loop.

Comment: What about using array ? : http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays do exactly this! See this example:

```
Dim Port(1 to 100) As String
Dim i As Long

Port(1) = "String"
For i = 2 to 100
    Port(i) = "String " & i
Next i
```

It sets Port(1), the first array element to the word "String". Everything else `Port(2)` and on, contain "String 2", "String 3", etc. Up to `Port(100)`.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you AndASM, I will try and it sounds the right way to go. I ignored there were arrays in VBA (very stupid of me…!!!) Thanks.